# A confusion between dB and dBVrms

Tags: signal

dB is always power ratio and we can write it in terms of voltage ratio.

Imagine Vx = Vs*sin(wt) where Vs is the amplitude.

In the case of dBVrms the Vref is 1V rms. So:

dBVrms = 20*log10(Vs/sqrt(2))

But if we would take the nominator as amplitude as Vs (i.e not rms value but the amplitude) then:

dB = 20*log10(Vs)

I'm kind of confused which one is the real dB here. I might be also mixing things here.

When we plot FFT power spectrum which one is relevant dB or dBVrms? What is the difference in use?

Comment: dB is relevant to power spectrum which can be normalized to max input range as 0 or 1mW into 50 Ohms as 0dBm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dB is used to represent a **ratio**.

For ratios of voltages, currents etc (not power) the formula is:

\$x\space dB = 20\space log \space \frac {V_{out}} {V_{in}} \$

For ratios of power, the formula is:

\$y\space dB = 10\space log \space \frac {P_{out}} {P_{in}} \$

To express a voltage in dBVrms (so relative to 1 Vrms) just fill in \$V_{in}\$ and \$V_{out}\$ in Volts, rms.

To express a voltage in dBVpeak (so relative to 1 Vpeak) just fill in \$V_{in}\$ and \$V_{out}\$ in Volts, peak.

You already know that \$V_{p} = {\sqrt2} \space V_{rms}\$ and you used that above.

Indeed you're mixing things and that's **OK** but mind that that introduces more complexity and it is then easier to make a mistake. I prefer to keeps things separate and in the "dB" formula stick to same way to express a voltage, so peak **or** rms.

*But if we would take the nominator as amplitude as Vs (i.e not rms value but the amplitude) then: dB = 20*log10(Vs)*

That is correct but you didn't specify what Vs is, is it peak or rms? You should specify what Vs represents to make things clear.

You can plot an FFT spectrum in either dB or dBVrms. But if you plot a spectrum in dB the first thing I will ask is: "dB compared to what?" Often it will be 1 Volt peak but it is better to explicitly state that.

When your FFT plot in dBVrms I do not need to ask as your reference ( 0 dB) should then be 1 V rms.

On spectrum analyzers often dBm is used and that means 0 dB = 1 milliWatt of power in 50 ohms (most spectrum analyzers have a 50 ohms input).

In communication technology often dBc is used, dBc means power level relative to a **carrier signal**, for example the level of a signal you're trying to receive in a receiver.

So: dB is relative, be clear what your reference (0 dB) is!

Answer (score 2):

When you start to use non RMS values to calculate decibel ratios (or relative values) then you get muddled up. For instance why would you want to compare the peak amplitude of a sinewave (Vs) with the RMS value of 1 V RMS? Maybe that is your confusion... When you say

> Vx = Vs*sin(wt) where Vs is the amplitude

Vs is the peak sine amplitude and not the RMS amplitude - are you aware of that?

> When we plot FFT power spectrum which one is relevant dB or dBVrms?
>   What is the difference in use?

A power spectrum is usually relative to some RMS reference so it's not all that useful to express it as plain dB unless one is interested in the relative amplitudes of parts of the spectrum.